# Checking for DOS files on UNIX

Tags: unix, dos2unix

I want to check whether any DOS files exist in any specific directory.
Is there any way to distinguish DOS files from UNIX apart from the ^M chars ?

I tried using file, but it gives the same output for both.

```
$ file test_file
test_file: ascii text
```

And after conversion:

```
$ unix2dos test_file test_file
$ file test_file.txt
test_file.txt: ascii text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CRLF (`\r\n`, `^M`) line endings chars are the only difference between Unix and DOS/Windows ASCII files, so no, there's no other way.

What you might try if you have to [`fromdos`](http://man.cx/dos2unix) command is to compare its output with the original file:

```
file=test_file
fromdos < $file | cmp $file -
```

This fails (non-zero `$?`) if `fromdos` stripped any `\r` away.

`dos2unix` might be used in a similar way, but I don't know its exact syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually put Windows newlines in, you'll see the following output from `file`:

```
 test_file.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Comment: Not on every version of Unix.